# VS Code showing React icon for .jsx file, but not for .tsx file

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js13

I've started to learn next.js 13 using VS code, I noticed that .jsx files are shown with React icon but .tsx files are not, how can I change that?

[.jsx vs .tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAYq8.png)

Created project via npx create-next-app, installed Microsoft's JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension

Comment: Install **VS Code Icons** extension After installing close and restart Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the vscode file icons with an icon theme.
I have prefer the [Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme).

It shows .jsx and .tsx like this:

[image]

You get a lot of other options when you search for `tag:icon-theme` in the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3Aicon-theme&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).